# How can I hide a table row based on selection made in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu that I would like to hide when France is selected in a dropdown menu in another row. I would like to hide the entire row so that County and the dropdown menu are hidden. Below is the CSS, JS that I have tried, and a link to the same in JSFiddle.

```
<table>
<tr>

<td class="BBFieldCaption DonationCaptureFieldCaption" id="PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_lbl_country">
<label id="PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_lblCountry" for="PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_dd_Country">Country:</label>
</td>

<td>
<select class="BBFormSelectList DonationCaptureSelectList" id="PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_dd_Country" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'PC1920$DonationCapture1$AddressCtl$dd_Country\',\'\')', 0)" name="PC1920$DonationCapture1$AddressCtl$dd_Country">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="France" selected="selected">France</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Italy">Italy</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="BBFieldCaption DonationCaptureFieldCaption" id="PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_lbl_countyUK">
<label id="PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_lblCountyUK" for="PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_dd_CountyUK">County:</label>
</td>

<td class="taLeft BBFieldControlCell DonationCaptureFieldControlCell" id="PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_ctl_countyUK">
<select class="BBFormSelectList DonationCaptureSelectList" id="PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_dd_CountyUK" name="PC1920$DonationCapture1$AddressCtl$dd_CountyUK">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="Alcorn">Alcorn</option>
<option value="Alexander">Alexander</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have tried doing this with jquery by adding the following but have been unable to get this to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_dd_Country').change(function() {
PC1920$DonationCapture1$AddressCtl$dd_Country = $('#PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_dd_Country').val();

$('PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_ctl_countyUK').hide();

if (PC1920$DonationCapture1$AddressCtl$dd_Country == 'France')
{
 $('PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_ctl_countyUK').hide();
}

});
});
```

I do not have direct access to the HTML for the form, this is using a CMS system. I have also added this to JSFiddle, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/qG2bT/7/

Comment: give us fiddle link .

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a # in your selector. Change

```
if (PC1920$DonationCapture1$AddressCtl$dd_Country == 'France')
{
     $('PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_ctl_countyUK').hide();
}
```

to

```
if (PC1920$DonationCapture1$AddressCtl$dd_Country == 'France')
{
     $('#PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_ctl_countyUK').hide();
}
```

Comment: Also your fiddle doesn't work because jQuery isn't included, and the __doPostBack function is not defined, causing javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#PC1920_DonationCapture1_AddressCtl_dd_Country').change(function () {
         $(this).parents('tr').next().toggle($(this).val() !== "France");
     });
 });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TEa8v/)

Comment: Can we do this by selecting the row id rather than the next row? In the actual form the row I would like to hide is further down the form but it was a lot of code to add here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nm, I think I got it :)